# Cannot resolve this symbol for an Object

Tags: java, android, xml, android-radiogroup

On creating an object RadioGroup in OnCreate() , when later this object is called in another function it shows the error "cannot resolve this symbol"

Here is java code
`MainActivity.java`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RadioGroup group1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que1_rG);
        RadioGroup group2 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que2rG);
        RadioGroup group3 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que3rG);
        RadioGroup group4 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que4rG);
        RadioGroup group5 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que5rG);
        RadioGroup group6 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que6rG);
        RadioGroup group7 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que7rG);
        RadioGroup group8 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que8rG);
        RadioGroup group9 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que9rG);
        RadioGroup group10 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que10rG);
    }

    public void submitButton(View view)
    {
        int checkedRadio1= group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Score is : " + score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.v("MainActivity","Score is  " + score);
        score = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting cannot resolve symbol is because you haven't declared your `RadioGroup group1` at class level. Since you have declared and assigned in `onCreate` its scope is limited to `onCreate()` only. To access in other method make it as class member.

Declare `RadioGroup group1` as class member as follows:

```
public class MainAcivity extends Activity{
    private RadioGroup group1;
    //Declare other RadioGroup group2,group3...group 10. if you intend
    //to access them outside of onCreate()
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        group1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que1_rG);
        ...
    }
      public void submitButton(View view) {
        int checkedRadio1= group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Score is : " + score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("MainActivity","Score is  " + score);
        score = 0;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Same thing applies for any other `RadioGroup`, which you would like to access outside of `onCreate()`.

You are also missing call to `show()` method while trying to display `Toast`. Without calling `show()`, Toast message won't be displayed.

**Instead of**

`Toast.makeText(this,"Score is : " + score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)`

**Use**

`Toast.makeText(this,"Score is : " + score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Comment: Thank you for giving that extra piece of advised I had totaly forgot about show() and hence I was using Log.v() to see the result , I kept wondering why its not working. Thanks

Comment: @VedantTripathi no problem. Enjoy coding :-) Remember to mark answer as accepted if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Declare Radio group button at class level. You are using veriable at function level so you can not use that variable out of the function.

```
   private RadioGroup group1, group2, group3, group4, group5, group6, group7,group8,group9,group10;     

    @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                 group1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que1_rG);
                 group2 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que2rG);
                 group3 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que3rG);
                 group4 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que4rG);
                 group5 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que5rG);
                 group6 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que6rG);
                 group7 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que7rG);
                 group8 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que8rG);
                 group9 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que9rG);
                 group10 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.que10rG);
            }

            public void submitButton(View view)
            {
                int checkedRadio1= group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Toast.makeText(this,"Score is : " + score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                Log.v("MainActivity","Score is  " + score);
                score = 0;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am an Idiot after seeing the solution ,I went and wrote the code while I could've had just copied from you.